# Taking two 120 volt outlets and combining into 240 volts

Tags: voltage

So before I begin let me say I am a complete idiot when it comes to anything electrical besides the very basics. So I am working on a project where I am powering something that needs 240 volts AC. So what I have done is taken two male outlets and wired them with 10 gauge wire to a common female plug. I have attached a picture below.
[image]

[image]

Now this is where my lack of electrical knowledge is hurting me here. When I plug these into different outlets it only gives 120 volts. I have done some research and found out they need to be on different circuts so I tried that as well. Only gave me 120 volts. I also heard something about being "180 degrees out of phase". Now please don't bully me too much but I have absolutely no idea what that means. If anybody could help me out that would be great. Also if you need more pictures I would be glad to supply them.

Comment: How have you wired that Y-cord?  If the "hot" wires from the two male plugs are connected together, you can only get 120 volts.  If you plug them into outlets that are on opposite "phases", you will blow circuit breakers. Attempting to get 240 V like that is extremely hazardous if you don't know what you are doing (and not advised if you do know what you are doing!)  You can get 240 V from a stove or clothes dryer outlet. (but you should still know what you are doing - call an electrician if you don't know).

Comment: @PeterBennett If the hot wires are not supposed to be touching how would it be wired. The way it is currently wired the 2 neutrals are touching, the 2 hots are touching, and the 2 grounds are touching.

Comment: DO NOT attempt to use your Y-cord to get 240 V - you'll blow breakers and may cause fires.  As you admit that you are a "complete idiot" re electricity, I strongly suggest that you consult an electrician if you need a 240 volt outlet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not only based on a faulty premise, but it is EXTRAORDINARILY DANGEROUS and should not be published online even as a way to NOT do something.

Comment: Yeah, that Y cable should be destroyed. But I did see a video on youtube once where a guy (not an idiot) did something similar to get 240 in Canada. He asserted that in Canada, most outlets have two 120V plugs which are out of phase from each other. Thus giving 240. But I wouldn't expect it work in the US.

Comment: @mkeith It is perfectly doable in the US, assuming you have outlets on opposite legs of the 240V feed. The problem is that that if you plug in only 1 plug and the 240V load, you will have 120 volts on the hot prong of the other plug!

Comment: @DoxyLover, he said that in Canada it is standard that the two plugs in the same outlet are typically from separate phases. From what I have seen in the US the two plugs in the same outlet are always the same phase (usually there is only one hot wire in the box). I'll try to find the video.

Comment: You can't combine 2 outlets to double the voltage. That's not how it works in this case.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I thought you meant separate outlets.

Comment: @DoxyLover
Here is the video. It is in the first 45 seconds.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UU-Gykz2ADY&index=15&list=PLF6EF6609E8BD58B9

Comment: In addition to everything else wrong with this idea, you are trying to put 240VAC on an outlet designed for 120VAC.  It isn't rated for the voltage, so isn't safe.  It also tempts people to plug a 120VAC rated appliance into something that could supple 240VAC.  If it worked, you would have 240VAC on a 120VAC outlet into which you could plug a 110VAC appliance.  DO NOT do this.  If you need a 240VAC outlet, then get one that is rated for 240VAC, and get the plug that goes with it to connect your 240VAC appliance.

Comment: In the US (and apparently Canada) it is common to provide 2 x 110 VAC "phases" by centre tapping a 220 VAC transformer winding, grounding the centre tap and distributing the 2 x 110 VAC outer ends as 2 x 110 VAC wrt centre tap. They are out of phase by 180 degrees (being opposite end of the same winding) and have 220 VAC available between them. These are not TRUE phases in the usual sense but are each separate halves of a 220 VAC single true phase. | IF you plug the Y cable into two such outlets on different phaaes you will short 'phase' to 'phase' and at best blow a fuse or trip a breaker.

Answer (score 5):

If you try to understand how the 120/240Vac 60Hz is distributed, you would need  a much longer Y adapter to combine opposite phases to get 240V.  Each phase labelled as Line 1 and Line 2 (Black and Red) in North American standards is distributed around the house to balance the load, and both are wired to the oven and electric dryer.   IN North America a differnt larger plug and outpet is used for 240Vac and NEVER the same as used for 120Vac.
[image]
- > But they are never both wired to a dual low current outlet. (10~20A)

The usual method is a 240 V cable direct from the breaker panel as adjacent dual outlets always have the same phase wired to them.  Water heaters rated for 240 do not need neutral so a 2 wire +gnd is all that is needed while a stove/oven requires both L1,L2 and N for 120Vac lights, clock and accessory outlets, so a 3 wire power cable + gnd is used.

Normally household wire is Black (Line=hot) and WHite (neutral) and Black may be used for either Line 1 or Line 2.

> ## Thus your example Y cable is a mistake in understanding.

[image]
[image]

Comment: the problem with a "properly" wired 2x120v-to-240v cable is that if you connect the 240v load and only plug in **one** 120v plug, the hot prong of the other plug will have 120 volts on it, conducted through the load device. Ready to electrocute a careless user! Also, this will not work at all on GFCI outlets or circuits.

Comment: I can't imagine anyone trying to do this except candidates for the Darwinian Awards.

Answer (score 1):

This "solution" is so wrong on so many levels it is hard to know where to start. The solution shown is practically DESIGNED to both electrocute you AND burn down your house.  Absolutely **NOT RECOMMENDED** in any way, shape or form.

There are two acceptable and safe ways of getting 240V for your project:

1. Wire a proper 240V circuit from the power distribution breaker box.
2. Use a 120V to 240V step-up transformer.  (Assuming sufficient power for your undisclosed requirements.)

Answer (score 0):

Tony's answer gave you the theory without explicitly telling how to "correctly" wire your cable. I'm not going to either. I want to make sure you understand the hazard. If you connect your 240 volt load, turn it on but only plug in one of the 120v plugs and then grab the prongs of the other plug, you will get a heck of a shock and could be electrocuted!

The 120 voltage enters through the hot prong of the plugged-in plug, conducts through the 240 volt device and ends up on the other plug's hot prong where it's just too easy to touch.

Don't do it!

BTW, it also won't work at all if your 120v outlets are GFCI or on GFCI breakers.